# Reset all customer address in magento

Tags: sql, magento

Had a problem with my payment module in magento. Some users have registered Number + Name of Street / Avenue apartment + number + zip code the same text field and fail to complete the checkout... I change this possibility on my form. But now I am looking for a way to reset the addresses.

I have not much knowledge in database magento. I wonder if anyone would know if it is possible to reset only the address of my customers using SQL or just the fields and tables so that I can create the script.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update all customer address by placing a php script in your root directory and running it one time. I have just added street field in this example. You need add other fields as well that you need to change. Make sure you understand this code and take a backup if necessary.

```
require "app/Mage.php";
$app = Mage::app('default'); 
$customers = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('BillingAddress');

foreach ($customers as $customer){
    foreach ($customer->getAddresses() as $address)
    {
    $data = $address->getData();    
    $newAddress=''; 
    $data['street']=$newAddress;
    $address->setData($data);
    $address->save();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to reset customer address is by making use of Magento Import/Export Option.

- Export all customers
  `Admin->System->Import/Export->Export->Export Settings->Customers`
- Make the changes as you wish/Fix the field blank if necessary.
- Import by selecting the Replacing existing complex data Option
  `Admin->System->Import/Export->Import->Import Behavior->Replace
  Existing Complex Data`
  And now the changes has been updated for all customers.
  If you want to remove the entire customers just change the `Import Behavior` to `Delete Entities` while `Import`.